# GetValue return Object does not match target type

Tags: c#, reflection

Already spend one hour trying to solve the problem with GetValue which always return

"`GetValue return Object does not match target type`".

I need to read API abstract property value from child class, any suggestion how to do that?

The classes

```
Parent
public abstract partial class EntityBase
{
   public abstract int Api { get; }
}

Child
public sealed class Email2Pdf : EntityBase
{
  public override int Api
  {
    get { return 12; }
  }
}
```

The actual code which gives exception

```
var subClasses = typeof(EntityBase).GetSubClasses(true);
foreach (var subClass in subClasses)
{
 //I always get exception here!!!
 var value = subClass.GetProperty("Api", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).GetValue(subClass, null); 
}

     public static class TypeExtensions
        {
            public static List<Type> GetSubClasses(this Type baseType, bool topMostOnly = false)
            {
                var subClasses = baseType.Assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(baseType)).ToList();

                if (topMostOnly)
                {
                    subClasses.RemoveAll(subClass => subClass.IsAbstract);
                }

                return subClasses;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of `GetValue` is the object to get the property value for. You are passing an instance of the `System.Type` class, hence the error. You need to pass an instance of the associated type.

Assuming each subclass has a default constructor, you can create one with Activator.CreateInstance e.g.

```
foreach (var subClass in subClasses)
{
   var instance = (EntityBase)Activator.CreateInstance(subClass);
   var value = subClass.GetProperty("Api", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).GetValue(instance, null); 
}
```

Comment: Could you post a example, I just lost?